# Вопрос по socket.io (node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, чат, chat

### Доброго времени суток дорогие друзья.

---

Вообщем я создаю чат рулетку на **node.js** и **socket.io** и в ходе разработки у меня вазникло несколько вопрос.

1. Чтобы отправить сообщение в нужную комнату я отправляю пользователю,
   значение его комнаты и создаю куки со значением данной комнаты. Как
   можно сделать это по другому?(У меня не получается вывести значение
   в переменную из анонимной функции.)
2. Я создаю куки с уникальным id пользователя, но я читал что как-то
   можно вытащить уникальный id с помощью **socket.io**
3. Я подключаю людей в комнаты без рандома, т.е. 1-2 пользователя в
   комнату0, 3-4 в комнату1 и т.д. Я читал что можно сделать массив с
   пользователями которые хотят общаться и подключать их друг к другу,
   но не совсем понимаю как это реализовать.

---

**P.s.** Возможно вам покажутся мои вопросы слишком глупыми, но они для меня правда не очевидны.

**P.s.s.** Я искал ответы на вопросы в гугле, но не нашел то что мне нужно.

**P.s.s.s.** Мне будет очень приятно, если вы ответите на мои вопросы :3

Comment: Поищите тут: https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=nodejs+socket.io+chat&type=

Comment: используй webrtc socket.id - уникальный могу дать готовый чат с комнатами

Comment: @SergeEsmanovich странное предложение, когда стек для разработки у топика и так хороший для выполнения поставленной задачи

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев не совсем хороший webrtc  будет быстрее и не требует сервера, будет работать также как hangouts (p2p)

Comment: @SergeEsmanovich обрабатывать нужно, в этом то и дело. Нужен сервер чтобы никто ничего не мог подменить. Сервер должен результат отдавать между 2 людьми. Я просто не пойму в чем сложность, когда тут примитивная логика

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев есть хорошие примеры где можно модерировать чаты

Comment: Вот держи тут набросок, не уверен что работает, но в коде сможешь подсмотреть начало, там ещё на 1-м ангуляре на него внимания не обращай=)
 https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B27Ry5HrqVubdUhLZUpuVm1hWjg

Comment: Я рад что вы пытаетесь мне помочь, большое спасибо)